# AngularJS - Bind click event to element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have the following partial being inserted into an ng-view.  I'm only pasting the part of the partial that is relevant.

```
<tr ng-repeat="group in groups">
    <td><a href="" class="restaurant-group-edit" create-link>{{ group.name }}</a></td>
    <td>{{ group.members.length }}</td>
    <td>{{ 5 }}</td>
    <td style="text-align: right">
    <span class="pseudo-select enhanced-select ps-settings">
        <select class="enhanced-select ps-settings restaurant-group-select" restaurant_group_id="1">
            <option value="actions">Actions</option>
            <option value="edit">Edit</option>
            <option value="edit">Restaurants</option>
            <option value="delete">Menus</option>
            <option value="edit">Delete</option>
        </select>
        <span class="es-label">Actions</span>
        <span class="icon"></span>
    </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I would like to bind a click event to each of the anchor elements above. I've tried this with a custom directive named create-link. In my app.js file I have the following code.

```
adminApp.directive("create-link", function($location, $timeout, $rootScope) {
    console.log("I fired the directive!");
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, element) {
            $timeout(function(){
                element.on("click", function(e) {
                    console.log("Clicked!");
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

However, the event is never bound. In fact, the "I fired the directive!" never actually gets written to the console. What am I missing here? Binding events to DOM elements that are created while loading the view would seem to be a common use case.  Surely there is an easy way to go about doing it.

Thanks for any help.

Andrew

Comment: Use `e.preventDefault() `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the directive name in js to the camelcased version of your directive name declared in view part:

```
adminApp.directive("createLink", function($location, $timeout, $rootScope) {
    console.log("I fired the directive!");
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, element) {
            $timeout(function(){
                element.on("click", function(e) {
                    console.log("Clicked!");
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  It's the little things that get you. :-)